# How do I add a link in a Trello checklist item?

Tags: trello, links

I tried using Markdown to add a link to a checklist item in Trello, but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Feature requests would go directly to support@trello.com - Your question has been reworded to make it on topic for Web Apps.

Answer (score 9):

It would appear that you cannot create a clickable link in a list item. However, you can create a clickable link in the Description area (back of card) by simply putting in a well formed URL, such as http://google.com And you could create a list of such links using Markdown syntax. Start each line with either an asterisk or a number followed by a period.

```
Of course you could also 
Use [Markdown Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax "Markdown") for an inline link.
```

to produce:

Of course you could also 
Use [Markdown Syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) for an inline link.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this feature wasn't around when this question was asked, but things have definitely changed :)

[image: How to add a link to a checklist in Trello]

[source](https://help.trello.com/article/821-using-markdown-in-trello)